# Partition external HDD into exFAT and NTFS partitions

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive

So I use a 1 TB external HDD formatted to exFAT for ps4 games. I have a 60 - 70 GB movie file that I want to watch on my TV (which supports NTFS only). Is there a way to add NTFS partition alongside exFAT? eg: 900 GB exFAT for ps4 and 100 GB NTFS for movies

Answer (score 0):

This needs to be done on a computer, but there is nothing to stop you from
partitioning the disk into two partitions and formatting each one with a different
file-system type.

The problem would rather be to find out if your devices are capable of
reading such a disk, as
some devices will only be able to use the first partition of the disk.

You will just need to try and see. I suggest to put the TV partition first,
as it is a more primitive device and may not have the ability to select
the second partition.